# Passing string array to the function C++

Tags: c++, string, function

I want to pass a string array to the function like this `int function (string text[])` . But the IntelliSense says that  identifier string is undefined . Why can't I pass a string array like usually I do with int arrays ?

Comment: _IntelliSense_ is not a definitive say on whether your code works or not, what happens if you compile it?

Comment: Do you have `#include <string>` and `using std::string`?

Comment: Because `int` is a built-in datatype while `string` is a datatype created using built-in types and exposed via the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `std::string` or just `string`?  Try adding `using std::string` if you don't have it in your code.

Comment: I have written using namespace std;

Comment: What about `#include <string>`?

Comment: @Sam379 Don't do `using namespace std`, see why [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: now everything is OK . I haven't included string library . Thanks